# How can I animate a procedural sky in Godot without the stutters?

Tags: frame-rate, godot, procedural-generation, skybox, sky

I know that generating a sky is very resource-intensive. Every time I change the "time of day" so to say, the game stutters for like 1/4 of a second. Can I make the sky be generated in a separate thread so it doesn't lock up the main one?
Also, is there a way to change the framerate of the animation player so it doesn't generate a sky so frequently?

Comment: Try this approach: [Easy Day/Night Cycle in Godot (Tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEenlZLltOE)

Comment: Yeah, I've already seen the video. It's pretty good, but there is no sun, beautiful sunset colors, gradient, etc. That's the only reason I want to use procedural sky

Comment: For what I have found, Godot will use a thread for that already. You can change the playback speed of the animation player, but not really the frequency of updates (except from deciding if it uses physics framer or render frames). I made an stopwatch class here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/192198/10408 perhaps you can use that to drive it. Aside from that, you could look into third party sky assets or implementing the features from the procedural sky by other means.